# Webserver issues | PHP manager for IIS

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012

i am using windows server 2012 with IIS 8.

I installed PHP 5.5 via web platform installer, all installations were successful apart from "PHP manager for IIS".

Any ideas why? below I will insert logs:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 7/27/2014 0:58:28 Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00 Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe ===
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:434]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:434]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:434]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:434]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:434]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:434]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:434]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:434]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: Original package ==> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\13a4c5.msi
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE}'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:448]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 1
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE}'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2014-07-27T00.58.28\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.txt'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Command Line: ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Windows\system32 CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 CLIENTPROCESSID=2724 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{8D8467C1-C020-4CA9-BA2F-6BF285C32338}'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize: ''
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE}'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product Code from property table after transforms: '{E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE}'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product {E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE} is not managed.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Package name extracted from package path: 'PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Package to be registered: 'PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Running product '{E851486F-1FE2-44F0-85ED-F969088A68EE}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\system32'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '3'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '2724'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is 'bb5f7c89def01e4ebd016ff7891facce'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\Favorites
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:464]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:480]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:495]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Installer\13a4c5.msi'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PHPManager\58698059E6E09CCF19706DBF8B1331AB51BCC662\PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64.msi'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Font 3: -2147287038 
=== Logging started: 7/27/2014 0:58:28 ===
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2262 2: LaunchCondition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Action start 0:58:28: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:511]: Note: 1: 2235 2: 3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (s) (CC:44) [00:58:28:511]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE053.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (s) (CC:0C) [00:58:28:511]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (CC:0C) [00:58:28:511]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 660 (0x294).
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:558]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:558]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
Action start 0:58:28: DIRCA_CheckFX.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDFrameworkVersion'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: Allocating space...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDFrameworkVersion'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: Property 'VSDFrameworkVersion' retrieved with value '2.0.50727'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: Set VSDNETMSG with the FrameworkVersion.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDNETMSG'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: Allocating space...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:573] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDNETMSG'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Property 'VSDNETMSG' retrieved with value 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1]. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
MSI (s) (CC!88) [00:58:28:589]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VSDNETMSG property. Its current value is 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1]. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'. Its new value: 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'VSDNETMSG' to 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDNETURLMSG'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Allocating space...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDNETURLMSG'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Property 'VSDNETURLMSG' retrieved with value 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1]. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
MSI (s) (CC!88) [00:58:28:589]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying VSDNETURLMSG property. Its current value is 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1]. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?'. Its new value: 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'VSDNETURLMSG' to 'This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Getting framework methods...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Found CorBindToRuntime.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Found GetRequestedRuntimeInfo.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Determine size of property 'VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Allocating space...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: MsiGetPropertyW - Getting Property 'VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Property 'VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions' retrieved with value 'False'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: Calling GetRequestedRuntimeVersion...
DEBUG : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:589] [CheckFX ]: RESULT -2146232576
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:605] [CheckFX ]: Custom Action succeeded.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:605] [CheckFX ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '0'
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action ended 0:58:28: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 1.
Action start 0:58:28: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CompLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding IISREGISTRYVALUE property. Its value is '#8'.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action ended 0:58:28: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 0:58:28: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Skipping action: ERRCA_CANCELNEWERVERSION (condition is false)
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Doing action: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions
Action ended 0:58:28: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:605]: Note: 1: 2235 2: 3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions' 
MSI (s) (CC:A4) [00:58:28:605]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE0B2.tmp, Entrypoint: VsdLaunchConditions
Action start 0:58:28: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Enumerating table using SQL statement: 'SELECT * FROM `_VsdLaunchCondition`'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Calling MsiGetActiveDatabase...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiDatabaseOpenViewW - Prepare Database to view table...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: TMsiViewExecute - Open Database view on table...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:623] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Evaluating condition 'VersionNT64'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: RESULT: Condition is true. Nothing more to do.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Evaluating condition 'IISREGISTRYVALUE >= "#7"'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:636] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: RESULT: Condition is true. Nothing more to do.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Evaluating condition 'VSDFXAvailable'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: RESULT: Condition is false.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '2'...
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting Property Value...
MSI (s) (CC!8C) [00:58:28:651]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding HideFatalErrorForm property. Its value is 'TRUE'.
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: MsiSetPropertyW - Setting property 'HideFatalErrorForm' to 'TRUE'.
ERROR : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Custom Action failed with code: '1603'
INFO : [07/27/2014 00:58:28:651] [VsdLaunchConditions ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '1603'
CustomAction VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 0:58:28: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 0:58:28: INSTALL. Return value 3.
=== Logging stopped: 7/27/2014 0:58:28 ===
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:651]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:651]: Product: PHP Manager 1.2 for IIS 7 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:651]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: PHP Manager 1.2 for IIS 7. Product Version: 1.2.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: . Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:651]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (CC:38) [00:58:28:651]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (CC:E4) [00:58:28:667]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (CC:0C) [00:58:28:667]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:667]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied. Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (A4:94) [00:58:28:667]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/27/2014 0:58:28 ===
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to successfully install the PHP manager for IIS 8, you need the .NET 3.5 framework installed and enabled, and for some reason, that's not part of the setup, which does download the .NET 2.0 framework.

So, just add the .NET 3.5 framework manually (you can do so through the "add features" wizard), and the your PHP manager should install properly.  And don't forget to apply the security patches from Windows update for the new Frameworks before sending this box into production.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is a workaround for posted issue https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/workitem/1889 , but codeplex comments are busted at the moment so I can't make a link from there to here.

Comment: The old installers seemed to rely on .NET Framework 3.5. I hope the 2.0 installers can be free of that https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases/tag/v2.0-beta1

Answer (score 0):

The page below fixed my problem on Windows 10 but I imagine it would work on the server too.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8?auth=1

The fix is to modify HKLM/System/CCS/Services/W3SVC/Parameters/MajorVersion to 7 - See near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).